# Regex change href="link" to href="notify('link')"

Tags: c#, regex, url

Regex always make me scratching head.

In my Windows Store App, an html content `<a href="www.example.com">` need to be replaced to `<a href="javascript:window.external.notify('www.example.com')">` in order to intercept Navigation event in WebView.

I tried `Regex.Replace(content, "<a href=\"(.+)\">", "<a href=\"javascript:window.external.notify('\\0')\">");` but no luck.

Could you teach me how to do it in C#?

Comment: Have your read [**the answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) first?...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov // Yes, I read many words about *Do NOT parse HTML with Regex*, but my content is not so heavy, so it *would* be fine to treatment in this way. Parsing HTML and Requesting additional memory-burden process is overkill in my case.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov // Or, I appreciate if you give more appropriate approach to handle my work (with C#).

Comment: @Youngjae You mention headscratching with regex. Do you know RegexHero? It's a great tool to try out .Net regex: http://regexhero.net/tester/

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4231382/471272): please link to answer, not to non-answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace CSTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Regex re = new Regex("<a href=\"(.+)\">", RegexOptions.Compiled);

            string input = "<a href=\"www.example.com\">";
            string res = re.Replace(input, 
                "<a href=\"javascript:window.external.notify('$1')\">");

            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

You pretty much had it. Your only problem was that you were using `\\0` instead of `$1` for the matched group.

If you prefer to call the static version of `Regex.Replace`, you could use:

```
string res = Regex.Replace(input, 
    "<a href=\"(.+)\">", 
    "<a href=\"javascript:window.external.notify('$1')\">",
    RegexOptions.Compiled
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd give something like this a try:

```
Regex.Replace(content, "(?<=<a href=\").+(?=\">)", "javascript:window.external.notify('$0')");
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be using `$1` instead of `\\0`.

We use `$` for backreferences in c#.

Comment: \<number> is indeed used for backreferences in C#. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwdfzxy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx What we're dealing with here is a capture group, which are represented with $<number>: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @Joce thts strange , coz I keep getting this error : `prog.cs(14,63): error CS1009: Unrecognized escape sequence `\1'
Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings` tried here :  http://ideone.com/MvgIm4

Comment: you need to use either @"bla bla \1" (raw string) or "bla bla \\1" (escaped backslash).

Comment: can you edit and save it in another ideone, because when I change it to `\\1` it results to `\1`.

Comment: Which I see you do use... FYI, your code compile fine in VS2012: http://i.imgur.com/G2S8dxs.png

Comment: ooh there seems to be a misunderstanding , see here sir http://ideone.com/MvgIm4

Comment: the above only works if I change the `\\1` to `$1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51071/discussion-between-joce-and-aelor)